# Servlets: How to Manipulate URIs

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, uri

So I'm working on a blog, but I'm stumbeling on organizing content with clear URL paths. Basically, I want every post that is created to have a unique URL path like "http://www.site.com/article/article_name." At this point I have my URLs look like "http://www.site.com/article.jsp?article=article_name," where article.jsp generates different content through:

```
request.getParameter("requestedArticleName");
```

I'm aware of servlet mapping to invoke servlets based on URL patterns, but I'm not quite sure how that works, and whether if I need it at all.

Comment: Have you tried UrlRewriteFilter (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)?

Comment: No. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method you can use to achieve that is to create your own `Filter` that will receive all requests from http://www.site.com/article/* and redirect them to your article.jsp?name=*.

Example :

```
public class URLFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void  init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest p_oRequest, ServletResponse p_oResponse, FilterChain p_oChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String sName = oRequest.getRequestURI();

        if(sName.lastIndexOf('/') != -1)
        {
            sName = sName.substring(sName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // You could trap that in your article.jsp to show error message
            sName = "404";
        }

        p_oRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/article.jsp?name=" + sName).forward(p_oRequest,p_oResponse);
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to improve that and do some validation. Also this code has not been tested but is based on my JSF CMS URLFilter.

Don't forget to include this in your `web.xml` !

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>path.to.your.URLFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/article/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```